# Change page creation layout

Tags: posts

I would like to change the backend page creation from this layout:

[image]

**To this layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your second image is of the Classic Editor. You can get it by installing the Classic Editor plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Comment: Thank you Jacob!